# GeneratedValue UUID id not inserting to the postgres DB

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, entity

I have used the below code to create an UUID datatype column in JPA entity that similar to the column in PostgreSQL DB

Entity

```
@Column(name = "uid", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID uid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Table Column

```
uid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1() in PostgreSQL DB
```

When i tried to insert a new record the error show as

> "Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
>   statement" and "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "uid"
>   is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea"

How to convert the bytea uuid value to correspondent in DB?

Comment: Yeah got it, I had searched for a while and didn't find this particular solution. Thanks for the help.